# post-processing of KFold split in scikit_learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm using GridSearchCV for tuning the hyperparameters (C, gamma, kernel) in SVM, using counts as weights. But I need my data to be split sample-wise (i.e. elements from one sample are all in the same fold). This can be achieved with GroupKFold or PredefinedSplit.

But I need a custom method to be applied to the fold-split before training.

A toy example of my data:

```
     sample   status  element  count   X1      X2      X3      X4
0       s1      0       0000    0.4     0       0       0       0
1       s1      0       1111    0.25    1       1       1       1
2       s1      0       0111    0.15    0       1       1       1
3       s1      0       1001    0.2     1       0       0       1
4       s2      1       0000    0.1     0       0       0       0
5       s2      1       0111    0.05    0       1       1       1
6       s2      1       1010    0.65    1       0       1       0
7       s2      1       1000    0.2     1       0       0       0
8       s3      0       0000    0.3     0       0       0       0
9       s3      0       1001    0.45    1       0       0       1
10      s3      0       1000    0.25    1       0       0       0
11      s4      1       1111    0.5     1       1       1       1
12      s4      1       0111    0.2     0       1       1       1
13      s4      1       0001    0.3     0       0       0       1
```

Let's say, sample *s1* gets into the test fold, and samples *s2-s4* are used for training. I need to collapse identical elements and average their counts across samples within the test/train group.

Comment: are you asking about [LeaveOneGroupOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut)?

Comment: @MaxU: No, I'm not. I know about this one, but similarly to GroupKFold or PredefinedSplit, it deals only with the splitting. But I need to apply some post-processing to the split.

Comment: sorry, i'm not aware of such out of the box solution... I guess you would need to program it yourself